# RegEx to remove Brackets starting and ending

Tags: java, regex, jakarta-ee

I need help in forming a java regex to remove the brackets at starting and ending of an ldap query.
The cases it has to cover are:

```
1) (|(GROUP=temp1)(GROUP=temp2)(GROUP=temp3)(GROUP=temp4))
   to -> (GROUP=temp1)(GROUP=temp2)(GROUP=temp3)(GROUP=temp4)

basically, remove brackets starting and ending if only Pipe (|) symbol is present..

2) (GROUP=temp1) or (Group=*) -> should not do any changes
```

help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried using this: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html?

Comment: i am using \((.+)\)   but it is replacing the (GROUP=temp1) or (Group=*) with  GROUP=temp1 and Group=* , which i dont want..i need to execute only when there is a pipe(|) in the regex..may be doing string contains will achieve this..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this, and keep only the second group:

```
(\(\|)(?<=\(\|)(.*)(\))(?<=\)\))
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/1Zlhpd/3

This also could work, and keep the second group:

```
(\(\|)(.*)(\))
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/1Zlhpd/4